# "ifdef" in PowerPC Assembly

Tags: c, if-statement, assembly, conditional-compilation, powerpc

I want to make a ifdef condition in assembly code similar to the Pre-processor in C.

for example :

```
ifdef UNIT_TEST
b somewhere
else
b somewhere else
```

I'm using e200z6 PowerPC core.

Comment: Note that you _can_ run the C preprocessor over any kind of text file, including assembly sources. How useful this is depends on whether the text file uses `#` for other purposes.

Comment: This is more about preprocessing than actual assembly language; it might depend on the assembler (which generates the output) how to do this.

Comment: Creating a C project and putting the asm files there sounds like a plan. Then you should be able to use the C pre-processor just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally (and this is what we do in the powerpc part of the Linux kernel) we get the C preprocessor to preprocess the ASM files for us:

```
#ifdef UNIT_TEST
b test
#else
b work
#endif
```

Conventionally these files are labelled `.S` instead of `.s` or `.asm` to indicate that they are preprocessed.